"Since I was little boy": which grammar rule governs lack of indefinite article?
Let us inspect phrases like "Since I was boy...", "Since I was little boy..." etc.
Why don't we use the indefinite article "a" in front of the noun "boy" or the adjective "litle"?
Is this a mistake, a misprint, was the writer too lazy or is there indeed an obvious important English grammar rule that I don't know yet?
But how we process great emotion and crippling anxiety is what sets us apart. My own fear of death has been with me since I was boy.
That's London Academy of Sciences, my friends!!!
Well, if it was a mistake, then you must fire the proofreader immediately. He doesn't deserve his/her job.
If it isn't, then please could you kindly explain to me why isn't there any article? I repeat again, in Russian we have no articles at all.
I wonder if James K can answer my question. I feel he is an amazing man.
Also, what about "Little Boy" (bomb)?

Cite the source,  and if possible, the author. Please write the entire sentence, not just a fragment, and Include the links IN the question, please. Not in the comments.  If this was a tweet or a YouTube comment, just realize that people are lazy writers when their opinions don't count for anything.

Thanks a lot, @Mari-Lou A. I have edited my question, cited the source. Added bold font, though I am not sure if it's necessary.

This is the source, not the forum where it was reported: https://www.academyfilms.com/blog/color-me-unnerving-new-short-from-martin-de-thurah

This is the author, Martin de Thurah, a Danish film director and screen writer, who is presumably not a native speaker. It seems pretty clear that the author either didn't realize there should have been an article or it was a simple slip up. I'm sorry to say that the the question is not interesting, and does not require a remarkable answer.

I've edited again, deleted my forum hyperlink. I agree it's totally irrelevant. Still wonder to know about the bomb. I don't think "Little Boy" is telegraphic style. Am I right?

Alexander, making rude comments is not a good thing to do on this site.

"Little Boy" was the name of the bomb, so not governed by normal rules about articles.

I'm not the downvoter.

Two downvoters now.

I feel very sorry.  Could you please forgive me? I didn't want to harm anyone. I simply came here from a true Earth's heaven where people receive up to 188 upvotes on a single question.  https://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/33134-chto-vy-posovetuete-cheloveku-kotoryj-tolko-chto-zaregistrirovalsja-na-sajte.html    Dear brothers and sisters, if you want peace, a shelter and money (I do not write on BQ for money though), you can come to us and we will accept you and be grateful.  11 years, 3864 questions. I feel very guilty! Forgive me if possible, @Michael Harvey.

And I even deleted my previous comment if you permit me. Very guilty. Every sinner deserves forgiveness. Every single soul and heart has the right to live. Every person is the best in the world.

Here: Since I was a little boy, it should have a.

@Lambie, thanks a lot! Your comment is useful, I indeed respect you!

It is a mistake.
I can't think of any context in which since I was little boy or since I was boy would be grammatical.

Though it is possible to say  "(Ever) since I was little, I have loved trains."

@Mari Lou, absolutely no doubt. You are 100 % true. My case is when we have a noun. "Little" by itself is NOT a noun. It's an adjective. Thus, "I was little" is 100 % correct. Trust me, I had been studying English for 15+ years, although I am very far from perfection...
